# Add different fragment to an activity based on Intent-given identifier

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm working on an application where in layout `layout-small-portrait` I want to launch different fragments contained in a single "container activity", named `SingleActivity`. I will handle this differnetly in layouts `layout-land`, `layout-large` etc. but that is unrelated to my problem.

I have an activity `MainActivity` which is, as the name indicates, the main activity (launcher) of my application. This will initially contain a `ListFragment` with different items for the user to press.

Based on the item that the user presses the `SingleActivity` will launch and its content will correspond to a specific `Fragment` related to this item. My problem starts here. When the user presses an item I have a reference to the corresponding fragment I want to be displayed in `SingleFragment`. Illustrated below:

```
  String tag = myFragmentReference.getTag();
  Intent i = new Intent(this, SingleActivity.class);
  i.putExtra(SingleActivity.CONST_TAG, tag);
  startActivity(i);
```

The activity launches successfully. In `SingleActivity` I have the following `onCreate()` method:

```
...

// Retrieve the fragment tag from the intent
String tag = getIntent().getStringExtra(CONST_TAG);
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

if(fragment == null) {
    // always end up here, this is my problem.
}

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
ft.commit();

...
```

I suspect that the fact that `fragment` is always `null` is because the fragment has not been inflated yet. If I am right what I need to do is define a fragment's tag before it is inflated, so that it can be found by `findFragmentByTag()`. Is that possible?

If anything is unclear please let me know.

I look forward to hearing some good ideas! If there are better or more clever ways to implement this I would love to hear your thoughts! Thanks :)

Comment: First try out to clean up your question, You tell us about a history with different viewpoints, First do you want to know how to create a menu inside MainActivity that you can use inside all Fragments, thats is it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've now cleaned up the question significantly.

Comment: Do you need this Indentifier or you just want to change the Fragment based on a useraction?

Comment: I just want SingleActivity to display a different fragment based on which item in the ListFragment (MainActivity) the user presses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are jumping to another activity, it will have its own Fragment BackStack and that fragment will not exist.

You will have to inflate the fragment in the new activity something along these lines:

```
String tag = intent.getStringExtra(CONST_TAG);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, tag, extras);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

The tag string will need to have the package location of the fragment such as "com.android.myprojectname.myfragment"

Answer (score 1):

First use SlidingMenu library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
This will help you, and your app will be more cool, that´s the only way that I can help you make what you need so, here is the code:

**Here is your MainActivity:**

I´ll try to explain this sample code and you use for your need.

**This is the ListFragment of your BehindContent (SlidingMenu):**

```
public class ColorMenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_names);
        ArrayAdapter<String> colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, colors);
        setListAdapter(colorAdapter);
//This array is only to fill SlidingMenu with a Simple String Color.
//I used MergeAdapter from Commonsware to create a very nice SlidingMenu.
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
//This switch case is a listener to select wish item user have been selected,  so it Call
//ColorFragment, you can change to Task1Fragment, Task2Fragment, Task3Fragment.
        Fragment newContent = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            newContent = new ColorFragment(R.color.red);
            break;
        case 1:
            newContent = new ColorFragment(R.color.green);
            break;
        case 2:
            newContent = new ColorFragment(R.color.blue);
            break;
        case 3:
            newContent = new ColorFragment(android.R.color.white);
            break;
        case 4:
            newContent = new ColorFragment(android.R.color.black);
            break;
        }
        if (newContent != null)
            switchFragment(newContent);
    }

    // the meat of switching the above fragment
    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (getActivity() == null)
            return;

        if (getActivity() instanceof FragmentChangeActivity) {
            FragmentChangeActivity fca = (FragmentChangeActivity) getActivity();
            fca.switchContent(fragment);
        } else if (getActivity() instanceof ResponsiveUIActivity) {
            ResponsiveUIActivity ra = (ResponsiveUIActivity) getActivity();
            ra.switchContent(fragment);
        }
    }


}
```

**Here is your BaseActivity Class:**

It dont have swipe, as I could understand, you don't need this.

```
public class FragmentChangeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Fragment mContent;

    public FragmentChangeActivity() {
        super(R.string.changing_fragments);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set the Above View
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        if (mContent == null)
            mContent = new ColorFragment(R.color.red);  

        // set the Above View
            //This will be the first AboveView
        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
        .commit();

        // set the Behind View
            //This is the SlidingMenu
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new ColorMenuFragment())
        .commit();

        // customize the SlidingMenu
            //This is opcional
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    }

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
            // the meat of switching fragment
        mContent = fragment;
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        .commit();
        getSlidingMenu().showContent();
    }

}
```

Ok, So If you want to change the ColorFragment to anything else, do this:

**First, choice the item that you want to use:**

```
case 0:
                newContent = new ColorFragment(R.color.red);
                break;
```

**to:**

```
case 0:
            newContent = new ArrayListFragment();
            break;
```

I have made just a arraylist, it is just a simple example, you can do a lot of thing, then you can read about Fragment to learn how to do different things.

```
public class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override                               
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Listnames.TITLES));
```

//Listnames is a class with String[] TITLES;

}

```
        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("FragmentList2", "Item clicked: " + id);

            String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

As you see, it can display a different fragment based on which item in the ListFragment (MainActivity) the user presses.

Well, if you misunderstood something, just tell me.

Comment: While I appriciate the effort in your answer, implementing it involves a lot of changes to my current setup. As Marco has a much simpler solution I will go ahead and implement that instead for now. I might come back and take a look at this later though as sliding menus sounds cool indeed.